# You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router> when dynamically rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

> `You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`

In error output line with: 'ReactDOM.render...' is highlighted.

That error occurs only when calling function `ReactDOM.render()`

Rendering component in `render()` works well.

```
  --- Parent.js ---
  import Child from './Child';

  export class Parent extends Component {    
        renderComponent() {
            ReactDOM.render(<Child />, 'id').
        }

        render() {  
           return (
              <div>
                  <button onClick={() => this.renderComponent()}/>  // error when clicked 
                  <Child />  // works fine
                  <div id="id"></div>
              </div>
             );
        }    
  }

  --- Child.js ---
  class Child extends Component {          
        render() {  
           return <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/')}/>;
        }    
  }
  export default withRouter(Child);

  --- App.js ---   
  export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
          return (
              <BrowserRouter>
                  <Route path="/parent" component={Parent} />
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              </BrowserRouter>
          );
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling ReactDom.render() inside your app that is already mounted. The render method in `Parent` will handle that just fine. You should be setting a state flag in `RenderComponent()` or if you want an array of `Child`'s, put your components onto an array of JSX components and just put that array in your render method.

**Flag**

```
export class Parent extends Component {    

    render() {  
       return (
          <div>
              <button onClick={() => this.setState({showChild: true})}/> 
              <Child />  // works fine
              <div id="id"> {this.state.showChild && <Child />} </div>
          </div>
         );
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, wouldn't expect that one. Cheers!